# Behavior of decltype

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, c++11, visual-c++, decltype

Say I have an object of some of stl container classes `obj`. I can define other object of same type this way:

```
decltype(obj) obj2;
```

But I can't declare iterator for the container this way:

```
decltype(obj)::iterator it = obj.begin();
```

Why? Am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Your code is well-formed according to the final C++0x draft (FDIS). This was a late change that's not yet been implemented by the Visual Studio compiler.

In the meantime, a workaround is to use a typedef:

```
typedef decltype(obj) obj_type;
obj_type::iterator it = obj.begin();
```

**EDIT:** The relevant chapter and verse is 5.1.1/8:

```
qualified-id:
    [...]
    nested-name-specifier templateopt unqualified-id

nested-name-specifier:
    [...]
    decltype-specifier ::

decltype-specifier:
    decltype ( expression )
```

And for completeness's sake:

[The original core issue](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2011/n3237.html#743)

[Proposal for wording](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2010/n3031.pdf)

Comment: Thank you @JohannesD. If you edit your answer adding paragraph number of final draft which tells this I'll accept your answer.

Answer (score 9):

It's because of the way that the language is parsed.

```
decltype(obj)::iterator it = obj.begin();
```

You want it to become

```
(decltype(obj)::iterator) it;
```

But in actual fact, it becomes

```
decltype(obj) (::iterator) it;
```

I have to admit, I was also surprised to see that this was the case, as I'm certain that I've done this before. However, in this case, you could just use `auto`, or even `decltype(obj.begin())`, but in addition, you *can* do

```
typedef decltype(obj) objtype;
objtype::iterator it;
```

Comment: Thank you for `auto`. But typedefing is not good idea in my opinion. I'm doing this to avoid typedefing.

Comment: @Mihran Hovsepyan: Why? Your code is depending on a Standard `typedef`- it's hardly `typedef`-free. `typedef` is hardly avoidable in C++ as it stands.

Comment: my class defination is in header, but methods in cpp, so every time during implementation of cpp I should open header and look what is the type of a member. But as every programmer I'm trying to be lazy))

Comment: @Mihran: I think that you are overdoing it... I reckon that you only have a couple of containers in the class, and that you can provide sensible names for them. Using those typedefs will make code more readable than using the intended `decltype(obj)::iterator`, and at any rate what DeadMG proposed can be a *local* typedef: `void X::foo() { typedef decltype(member) container_t; container_t::begin it...`, and that does not require you to go back and forth to the header... Then again I would not do that either...

Answer (score 2):

Yet another workaround until VC++'s parser is fixed to reflect the FDIS is to use the [`std::identity<>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee391705.aspx) metafunction:

```
std::identity<decltype(obj)>::type::iterator it = obj.begin();
```

Comment: FWIW, `std::identity` has been removed, so that's effectively VC2010 dependent. (It's simple enough to write it, though.)

Comment: @GMan : Right, I only mentioned it because the OP's question was VC++ 2010 specific. :-]