# How to get the last element of an std::unordered_map?

Tags: c++

How to get the last element of an `std::unordered_map`?

`myMap.rbegin()` and `--myMap.end()` are not possible.

Comment: the concepts of unordered and last seem to conflict

Comment: Well, when you iterate, it may be important to check whether you are finished or not (before hitting end() of course).

Comment: Then check if doing `++` gives you `end()`...

Comment: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/unordered_map

Answer (score 14, accepted):

There is no "last element" in a container that is **unordered**.

You might want an ordered container, e.g. `std::map` and access the last element with `mymap.rbegin()->first` (Also see [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1660195/c-how-to-find-the-biggest-key-in-a-stdmap))

**EDIT:**

To check if your iterator is going to hit the end, simply increment it (and possibly save it in a temporary) and check it against `mymap.end()`, or, even cleaner : `if (std::next(it) == last)`

Comment: Thanks. I need an unordered_map but I need to check when I am done before hitting end()... I could save the "previously iterated element though"... Just searching for some "clean solution".

Comment: Then why dont you check your iterator against `end()` as always ?

Comment: and keep the previously iterated item? This is what I did. I was just wondering if some "cleaner" would exist. Note that on Windows, rbegin is there^^

Comment: I doubt it, the standard explicity says that it does not exist on unordered containers ... See my edit, the clean way in your case is what you did : increment and compare to end()

Comment: @quantdev, shouldn't you do the `mymap.rbegin()->second` instead of first to get actually the last element?

Comment: @yerzhan7 'first' will get you the last key, 'second' will get you the last value, pick whichever suits your case

Answer (score 2):

In your comments, it appears your goal is to determine if you are on the last element when iterating forward.  This is a far easier problem to solve than finding the last element:

```
template<class Range, class Iterator>
bool is_last_element_of( Range const& r, Iterator&& it ) {
  using std::end;
  if (it == end(r)) return false;
  if (std::next(std::forward<Iterator>(it)) == end(r)) return true;
  return false;
}
```

the above should work on any iterable Range (including arrays, `std` containers, or custom containers).

We check if we are `end` (in which case, we aren't the last element, and advancing would be illegal).

If we aren't `end`, we see if `std::next` of us is `end`.  If so, we are the last element.

Otherwise, we are not.

This will not work on iterators that do not support multiple passes.

Answer (score 1):

You cant. by definition, the element is not stored based on some sort of order. the key is hashed first and that's why O(1) search is possible. if you wanna check whether a key exists in the unordered_map or not, u can use this code:

```
std::unordered_map dico;
if(dico.count(key)!=0){
    //code here
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
std::unordered_map::iterator last_elem;
for (std::unordered_map::iterator iter = myMap.begin(); iter != myMap.end(); iter++)
    last_elem = iter;
// use last_elem, which now points to the last element in the map
```

This will give you the last element in whatever order the map gives them to you.

**Edit:** You need to use `std::unordered_map<YourKeyType, YourValueType>` instead of just `std::unordered_map`. I just wrote it like this because you did not provide the type in your question.

Alternatively, as suggested by `vsoftco` (thanks), you could declare both `last_elem` and `iter` as `decltype(myMap)::iterator`.

(If you're compiling with the MSVC++ compiler, then you will need to add `typedef decltype(myMap) map_type;` and then instead of `decltype(myMap)::iterator` use `map_type::iterator`.)

Comment: What compiler are you using? MSVC++? This is not going to compile with clang I believe.

Comment: Where did you see `rbegin` in `unordered_map`?

Comment: unordered_map doesn't have reverse iterators. I wonder though why `std::prev(myMap.end())` doesn't work and segfaults.

Comment: I'm sorry everyone -- typo. I meant `begin`, not `rbegin`.

Comment: still incorrect, but close to  :), you need `decltype(myMap)::iterator last_elem;` and `decltype(myMap)::iterator iter` in the `for` loop

Comment: @vsoftco Err... actually, I just tested your suggestion, and it doesn't compile in MSVC++.

Comment: @Jashaszun it compiles on g++/clang++, my guess is MSVC++ is not really standard-compliant. See http://ideone.com/B0r8pI for live code, without `decltype` it spits an error. And for the iterator in the for loop, can just use `auto`

Comment: @vsoftco Ah. Yes, I see from [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6101728/behavior-of-decltype) that Visual Studio just hasn't implemented it yet.

Answer (score 1):

`.end()` is an iterator to the "element past the last element". That's why you compare it like this when you loop through a map:

```
for (auto it = myMap.begin(); it != myMap.end(); ++it) // '!=' operator here makes it possible to only work with valid elements
{
}
```

So you want the "last" element (whatever that may be, because it's not really guaranteed to be the last in an unordered map, since it ultimately depends on how the key was hashed and in which "bucket" it ends up in). Then you need: `--myMap.end()`

More specifically, `.end()` is a function, that returns an iterator, same as `.begin()` returns an iterator. Since there is no `.rbegin()` in an `std::unordered_map`, you have to use `--` (the decrement operator):

```
auto it = --myMap.end();
```

To access the key you use `it->first`, to access the value you use `it->second`.

Answer (score 0):

The accepted answer seems wrong.  Unordered_map does have the last element even though the key-value pair is not stored in sorted order.  Since the iterator of unorered_map is forwar_iterator(LegacyForwardIterator), the cost to find the last element is O(n).  Yakk - Adam gave the correct answer.  Essentially, you have to iterator the container from begin to end. At each iteration, you have to check whether the next element is end(); if yes then you are at the last element.

You cannot call prev(it) or --it.  There will be no syntax error, but you will have a runtime error (more likely segmentation fault) when using the prev(it) or --it. Maybe next version of compiler can tell you that you have an logic error.

Answer (score 0):

It may not be the best solution, performance-wise, but in C++11 and later, I use a combination of `std::next()` and `size()` to jump all elements from the beginning of the map, as shown below:

```
std::unordered_map<int,std::string> mapX;
...

if (mapX.size() > 0) {
   std::unordered_map<int,std::string>::iterator itLast =
      std::next(mapX.begin(), mapX.size() - 1);
   ...
```