# How does decltype work?

Tags: c++, c++11, decltype

Is it evaluated only on compile time? Does it look what is the expression type or it's return type and just substitutes it? I.e. does it work as macros preprocessor substitutions? Also if I wrote this:

```
std::map<std::string, int> m;
decltype(m.cbegin()) i;
```

Is it going to call actually the `cbegin` and I will pay for some performance here?

EDIT: I know already that I can write `decltype(m)::const_iterator i;`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`decltype` strictly works in compile time. As such, you can use it with code that would dereference `end` iterators, or use

```
decltype(sqrt(-1.))
```

There is absolutely no runtime penalty associated with this - it simply doesn't get executed.

---

Incidentally, regarding your comment:

You should use `decltype` with an expression that returns some value. Somewhat Ironically, `decltype(m)::const_iterator i;` is not an expression that returns a value - it is a *definition* of a value.

Comment: Thank Ami, but I didn't understood your last comment. I can write this: `int a = 1; decltype(a) b = 2;`. Here again we don't have and expression that returns some value, but defines a variable with name `b`.

Comment: Right, you can write `decltype(a)`, but not `decltype(int a)` - that's the point I was trying to make. Hope that clears it.

Comment: No, sorry. I didn't write `decltype(std::map<std::string, int> m)` but `decltype(m)`. I don't see the parallels. Please explain.

Comment: your expression is compiling fine: http://ideone.com/Nzik72 Ideone is using gcc 5.1, which compiler did you try?

Comment: @Anedar see this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6101728/behavior-of-decltype

Comment: @Narek: And the accepted answer on that question *clearly says* that C++11 allows you to do that. If some version of Visual Studio (or whatever compiler you're using which you refuse to name) doesn't, then it's *wrong*.

Comment: The question is how does `decltype` works not how to use it.

Answer (score 1):

> I cannot write decltype(m)::const_iterator i;

You can!

```
std::map<std::string, int> m;
decltype(m)::const_iterator i; // same as std::map<std::string, int>::const_iterator
```

GNU C++ compiles this snippet [well](http://goo.gl/l9GvNp).